# How to deploy django app using nginx+ waitress?

Tags: django, nginx, waitress

I want to deploy a django app on nginx. I am trying to deploy a  using nginx + waitress. The app is getting deployed successfully but when I check the response header the server header has the value waitress instead of nginx.[Response header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBdCx.png).
How to deploy it on nginx?